# Seeking for a lightweight, but flexible solution to log method entry and exit (possibly by an exception) with log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I need a lightweight solution, which would enable me to log method entry and/or exit and/or exception. I would like to be able to configure:

- The entry/exit/exception log level. For instance, I might have `Debug` level for exit, `Info` level for entry and `Error` level for exception.
- The entry/exit/exception log message. The log message should allow me to reference the method name, the method parameters and the method result.

Let us take this method, for example:

```
public ObjectB MyFunc(int x, string s, ObjectA y)
{
  // implementation
}
```

Then, assuming `@Log` is such a magic annotation, one could have any of these `@Log` annotations on the `MyFunc` method:

```
@Log                   // should be a reasonable default
@Log(EntryLevel = LogLevel.Info, ExitLevel = LogLevel.Debug) // makes sense to have  ExceptionLevel = LogLevel.Error by default
@Log(EntryText = "{method}({methodArguments}) = ?", ExitText = "{method} = {methodResult}")
@Log(EntryText = "{method}({@x}, {@s}, ...)")
```

Where:

- `{method}` would be replaced by "MyFunc"
- `{methodResult}` would be replaced by the `toString` of the method result
- `{@x}` would be replaced by the `toString` of the `x` method argument
- `{@s}` would be replaced by the `toString` of the `s` method argument
- `{@y}` would be replaced by the `toString` of the `y` method argument
- `{methodArguments}` would be replaced by something like **"x: `{@x}`, s: `{@s}`, y: `{@y}`"**, or **"`{@x}`, `{@s}`, `{@y}`"**, which could be governed by a boolean flag, like `includeArgumentName`.

For the record, in .NET we use a modified (by us) version of the Log4PostSharp library, which does all of the above by injecting the right bytecode during the compilation phase. Hence, I have a pretty good idea what I am looking for, though I have absolutely no idea how to do it in Java and whether something like this has already been done.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I would like to address the performance issue. The code may be abundant with the logging statements. Executing these statements must not incur any visible performance penalty when no actual logging is performed (due to log level constraints, for instance).

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) or AOP in general. The whole point of it is to let you wrap method calls like this using build-time / load-time instrumentation of bytecode. (Not sure if you can access method argument names though.) Unfortunately I've only actually used Spring Framework's proxy-based AOP, which is tailored to working with Spring constructs, so I don't have an example of setting things up handy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ)?  Some additional details are at http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/logging-with-aspectj/ and http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/10/logging-method-entryexit-with.html .

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there something more or less ready or will I have to implement most of the desired logic?

Comment: I added 2 links to other blogs that have implemented this.  Looks like using Spring along with AOP to accomplish this is pretty common.

Comment: I have read that Spring is much slower than AspectJ. Does it affect the logging performance - see my last minute edit of the post.

Comment: Spring isn't necessary for this, and is not a requirement nor replacement of AspectJ.  The first link doesn't even use Spring.  If you're seriously concerned with performance, the first thing I would do is swap out log4j with SLF4J and logback - and then make sure to use those libraries' performance features - including parameterized logging.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a classic AOP problem. 
Spring has a flexible solution that is relatively easy to use, see [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html).

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is there something more or less ready or will I have to implement most of the desired logic?

Comment: As was commented above by Inerdial, Spring provides a way to wrap classes with a proxy, which in turn can perform actions before or after method invocations.
I do recommend reading the entire page I've linked, but you can see in the example sections more or less how this is done.
Basically, you provide implementation to the logging mechanism itself, and then wire the calling mechanism by providing an expression that selects the relevant cases (by Class, method signature, or a few other options).